# Trouble solving task related to Fourier transforms

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-numbers, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I have been given that

$$\mathcal{F}\{xe^{-x^2}\} = - \frac{i\omega}{2^{3/2}} e^{-\frac{\omega^2}{4}} \tag{1}\label{1}.$$

I am supposed to use (1) and a table of known Fourier transforms to find the function $f$, when

$$xe^{-x^2} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(v)e^{-2(x-v)^2} dv \tag{2}\label{2}.$$

I have used the definition of the inverse-fourier transform, as well as attempting to Fourier transform both sides of (2), but none of those approaches yielded any results.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fourier transforming both sides should work fine. The trick is that you can separate the resulting double integral:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(v)e^{-2(x-v)^2}dv\right] =& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(v)e^{-2(x-v)^2}e^{-i\omega x}dvdx 
\\ =& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(v)e^{-i\omega v}dv\right]\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2(x-v)^2}e^{-i\omega (x-v)}dx\right]
\\ & = \sqrt{2\pi}\mathcal{F}[f]\mathcal{F}\left[e^{-2x^2}\right].
\end{align}
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I believe so. Didn't see that I could separate the double integral!